# Need to find final location of moveable UIImageView in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView that I am able to move on my screen.  However, what I would like to know is the center point of the UIImageView after the user has stopped moving it.  My UIImageView is located inside my main view.

I have tried using:

```
CGPoint centerPoint = _imageView.center;
```

but unfortunately, this value remains the same regardless of where I move the UIImageView on the screen.  How can I determine the center point of the UIImageView that is dynamic due to the fact that the user will be moving the UIImageView on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
CGRect frame = _imageView.frame;
```

And then do some math with the x coord, y coord, height, and width to get the center with respect to your main view.

Comment: I'd be careful with this if the screen is rotated, you won't get the correct answer. Using the center property is the way to do it. It would be better to find out why it's not working in the first place rather than suggesting a fragile workaround.

Comment: You're right, I've never actually used the center property and just looked it up.  I was thinking it gave the center of the element, not with respect to the superview.